# Данные не отображаются корректно || Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action

Мне нужно проверять данные в reducer и отталкиваясь от них изменять state.

---

Проблемный action в reducer:

**Скрин**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код**

```
case LOAD_CATEGORIES: 
        return {
            ...state,
            postState: {
                ...state.postState,
                categories: state.postState.posts.map(elem => {
                    console.log(state.postState.category) // тут всегда выводит пустой массив
                    return elem.category // данные добавляются
                })
            }
        }
```

action в компоненте вызываю один раз, в console выводит нормальный массив с нормальными значениями, а в action все пусто. В чем может быть проблема?

---

**Reducer**

**Скрин**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код**

```
export const blogReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOAD_CATEGORIES: 
            return {
                ...state,
                postState: {
                    ...state.postState,
                    categories: state.postState.posts.map(elem => {
                        console.log(state.postState.category) // тут всегда выводит пустой массив
                        return elem.category // данные добавляются
                    })
                }
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

---

**InitialState = state**

**Код**

```
const initialState = {
    filterState: {
        category: "All",
        search: ""
    },
    postState: {
        categories: [],
        posts: [],
        counter: 2
    },
    loaderPosts: false,
    admin: false
}
```

---

**Dispatch actions при загрузке страницы с постами**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**ReduxDevTools при загрузке страницы**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Loaders(визуально, для отображения загрузки)
2. SetNumberToCounterPosts(визуально, для отображения постов при нажатии Next)
3. SePostsRequest(приходят данные с сервера и помещаются в массив)
4. LoadCategory(проблемный action который я описывал выше)

---

**В консоле я вывожу данные state который видит action LOAD_CATEGORY при цикле**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные добавляются, но в categories их не видно

*** Если для полного понимания проблемы нужно предоставить еще скрины, напишите в комментарии ***

Comment: Выкладывайте код, а не скрины. Либо ссылку на codeopen  и тд

Comment: @1ocke добавил код скрина

Comment: console.log(state.postState.category) или console.log(state.postState.categories). Докинь, пожалуйста, inititalState или весь reducer

Comment: @Александр добавил

Comment: С reducer-ом всё хорошо, нужно проверять какие данные в postState.posts на момент срабатывание action.type, посты я надеюсь не с сервера приходят?

Comment: @Александр посты приходят с сервера, а потом обрабатываются. Последовательность там есть. А что может быть не так, если они будут приходить с сервера?

Comment: @Александр также хочу добавить. Я урезал фрагмент кода с reducer, для лучшего зрительного восприятия. Там был action который отвечал за получения постов с сервера, и другие. Если они пригодятся - напомните

Comment: @mbfilipp тогда интересно, где именно вызывается action, данные с сервера приходя асинхронно, возможно, что данные в state записались синхронно, а данные с севера ещё не пришли. Попробуйте, в консоль после LOAD_CATEGORIES закинуть postState и вызвать action

Comment: @mbfilipp если это не коммерческий проект, можно ссылку на git hub или песочницу?

Comment: @Александр проект к сожалению коммерческий, я предоставлю максимум скринов в ближайшее время для понимания проблемы

Comment: @Александр я старался описать проблему максимально подробно) Извините если слишком длинно. Если нужны еще скрины, я их добавлю

Comment: @mbfilipp спасибо, за старания, я пытался, реализовать ваш код, интересно всё таки понять, что не так, но у меня как не странно всё хорошо. Вам удалось решить эту проблему?

Comment: @Александр после откладок и деббагов, складывается ощущение, что измененный categories показывает только после окончания функции-цикла, а не в реальном времени. Еще не знаю как я буду решать эту проблему, но спасибо за старание и помощь в данном вопросе

Comment: @mbfilipp А может стоит попробовать ещё один action, после case LOAD_DATA, когда данные уже есть case SORT_DATA и вызывать этот action после цикла?

Comment: @Александр была такая идея, попробую реализовать

Comment: @Александр все получилось, реализовал вашу идею, все сортируется как надо. Большое спасибо за помощь, оставьте ответ с решением SORT_DATA, я отмечу его как правильный